# Cannot return an HTML view in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

It's my first attempt at using Spring and I ran into a problem. I cannot seem to return a simple HTML file as a view inside a controller. I'm trying to return the index.html file (it just has some text and a button), because it is displayed correctly when going to `localhost:8080/`.

The project was generated using IntelliJ, I figure I'd mention this since it handled most of the configuration.

Here's the file structure:

```
app:
 | src
    | main
       | java
          | com.my.testapp
              | Main.java
              | controllers
                  | TestController.java
       | resources
          | static
              | index.html
```

Here are my files:

Main.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

TestController.java (the first controller actually works)

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
@Controller
public class TestController
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/testget")
    public @ResponseBody ArrayList<Test> foo()
    {
        ArrayList<Test> tests = new ArrayList<>();

        tests.add(new Test("id1", "pass1"));
        tests.add(new Test("id2", "pass2"));

        return tests;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/someview")
    public String showView()
    {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And finally, the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>testapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>springtest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I was previously using @RestController annotation and the controller would simply return the string index, but now I get a 404 page (Whitelabel Error Page). I know this is a common issue, but I haven't been able to solve it using other people's solution.

**EDIT:** Ok, I managed to fix part of it by removing the line `@RequestMapping("/test")`, but I now need to pass the view as "index.html" instead of simply "index". Is there a way to skip the .html? Currently it doesn't work without it.

**EDIT #2:** I finally figured out how to make the views work properly, check my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of useless Google searches, two kind Indian dudes explaining stuff on YouTube and a few white hairs I finally got the app running properly. Here's everything I found out:

**File structure**

The structure I posted in my question is correct, no need to change anything. The HTML views can reside under `src/main/resources/static`.

**Returning HTML views using controllers**

I removed the annotation from the Controller class and now my simplified controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class TestController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/someview")
    public String showView()
    {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

You can add/map more URLs to this controller by changing the annotation to

`@RequestMapping(value = {"/someview", "/someotherview", "/onelastview"})`.

Now I can navigate to `localhost:8080/someview` and get the `index.html` view (without actually specifying the file extension in the controller).

**Extra configuration**

By default, my controller function needed to return `"index.html"` instead of `"index"`. The solution for this is to add a line to `application.properties`. This file resides (in my case) under the `resources` folder.

The line is `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html`. This specifies the type of the views. You can also set `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/path/to/views`, but I didn't know how to set it and it worked anyway (I guess that it defaults to `resources/static`).

This basically tells the framework to grab the views using the following path:

`prefix + viewName + suffix`, where viewName in my case is `index` (whatever String I return in my method).

`Main.java` required no extra configuration, just the `SpringApplication.run()` line.

Comment: Just by adding `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html` inside the file application.properties I could solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You need to define `ViewResolver` bean to let spring know where are your views

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    bean.setSuffix(".html");
    return bean;
}
```

Comment: extension is .html why your  configure .jsp

Comment: hmm I think it just an example and OP will fix it himself so I leave it as default. I will edit then

Comment: I tried this but changed "/WEB-INF/view/" with "resources/static/" (see the structure above) but I get the following Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config

Comment: Ok, I added the maven dependency for Jstl and it no longer throws an exception, but I now get 404 again.

Comment: try putting your html under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view` folder

Comment: Same thing. I am pretty sure it's not the file location that's the problem, but maybe some configuration I missed.

Comment: @Anh I removed the RequestMapping from the Controller and now it works (with resources/static). The last problem I have is that I have to return "index.html" as it doesn't simply recognize "index". Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I added `spring.mvc.view.suffix= .html` to my application.properties and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

Just try `"index.html"` instead of `"index"` in the return statement of your `showView()` method. Let me know if it works.

Comment: we are not provide the extensions in return statement.

Comment: I think it will not work without the `.html` extension. If you want to omit the extension you have to do additional configuration.

Comment: Please read the Spring MVC manual Properly before commenting.